# Node.js event handler does not work

Tags: node.js, events

Hello I am trying to build a Node.js app like this. The code in my app.js file is:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var employee = require('./employeeEmitter');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var data = [
    {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {id:2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {id:3, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
];
inherits(employee.EmployeeEmitter, EventEmitter);
var newEmployeeEmitter = new employee.EmployeeEmitter(data);
newEmployeeEmitter.on('lookupById',function(){newEmployeeEmitter.lookupById(newEmployeeEmitter.data,1)});
employee.EmployeeEmitter.prototype.test= function () {
        this.emit('lookupById');
}
console.log(newEmployeeEmitter.test);
```

In my employeeEmitter.js file:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
module.exports = {
    EmployeeEmitter: function (args) {
        this.data = args;
        EventEmitter.call(this);
    },
    lookupById : function(data,id){
        var foundId = _.where(data,{id:id});
        return foundId[0];
    },
    lookupByLastName : function(data,lastName) {
        return _.where(data,{lastName: lastName});
    },
    addEmployee: function (data, firstName, lastName) {
        // obtain next id
        var newId = function (data) {
            var id = _.max(data, function (data) {
                return data.id;
            });
            return id.id + 1;
        }
        // return new data (old data + new object, but without mutation of initial object)
        data.push( {id:newId(data), firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName });
        return data;
    }
}
```

I hope when I run the app.js, the output in console window should be:

{ id: 2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith' }

However, it shows [Function]. I don't know what happen. Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't actually call the test function, and when you emit events they don't return anything.

Something more like this may work:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var employee = require('./employeeEmitter');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var data = [
    {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {id:2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {id:3, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
];
inherits(employee.EmployeeEmitter, EventEmitter);
var newEmployeeEmitter = new employee.EmployeeEmitter(data);
newEmployeeEmitter.on('lookupById',function(){console.log(newEmployeeEmitter.lookupById(newEmployeeEmitter.data,1));});
employee.EmployeeEmitter.prototype.test= function () {
        this.emit('lookupById');
}
newEmployeeEmitter.test();
```

Comment: thank you. I changed to your code, which at last line using: newEmployeeEmitter.test(); however, it gives me another error:TypeError: newEmployeeEmitter.lookupById is not a function